# What is difference between avatar and Avataari?

Tags: gods, avatars

Load Krishna is avatar, lord Rama is also an avatar, so who is say Avataari?

What is big in both them?

Comment: I'm seriously confused .

Comment: Reference to context will help. Where did you see the term "avataari" ? Usually, the word avataari has a suffix such as "ta" making the word "avataarita" (a verb conjugation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lord Vishnu is the bramhan which has No Form or Name. This is called Moola Rupa of lord Narayana. During the start of new creation after maha pralaya, this entity or bramhan take the form of Bramha to do the creation, form of lord vishnu for protection and lord rudra/shiva for Layaa. Saying this moola rupa is visible as lord Vishnu in vaikunta and this visible rupa only operates to protect good/dharma from bad/adharma. This form of vishnu from vaikunta takes several avataras (it may be Amsha avatara or Purnavatara). Same moola rupa is also seen as krishna in Ghow lokha. So many of the avataras such as narasimha, parasurama are amsha avatara, a part of lord narayana thejas is in them. Bhagavatha describes 21 of such avataras.
Rama Avathara is one of the poornavatara as lord narayana came down to take birth with all his parivara gana (sudharshan , Adhisesha, Panchajanya) with goddess Rama/lakshmi.
Krishna avathara is the most poornavathara ("Krishnasthu Bhagavan Swayam") says the Bhagavatham. Because when Lord vishnu came as krishna both Lord from Vaikunta and Krishna From ghoo lokha combined into womb of devaki to take birth.
So to breif your answer lord vishnu moola rupa has taken two forms one in Vaikunta and one in ghoo lokha, the swami in vaikunta is the avathari in many avathars.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.